# Minecraft world reset after update - recoverable?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Windows 10 (bedrock edition).  I have a world that my kids and I have been playing in for quite some time and have done a lot of work to improve.  We all updated on various devices to v1.16.1.  My previous exit point of the game was IN the nether.  So, after the update, I started in the nether, passed through the portal, and came out into the middle of a block -- since the entire overworld appears to be reset, with everything we have created erased.

Now, I have tried pretty much everything I could find regarding creating a world with the same starting points (seed, settings, etc.) and copying DB files. I can't get this world back.  Basically, I have the db folder and its contents, and the size of the db folder (23MB) is the same as the reported world size before updating. I also have the inventory I had before the corruption / reset.

If I have the DB files, is there any way to get this thing back?  At this point, I'd be ok dealing with partial block resets, as long as I didn't lose the WHOLE thing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm surprised your overworld was reset; normally when an update occurs, it keeps the chunks from the previous version, and any undiscovered chunks will follow the new terrain generation. With that being said, you won't be able to generate a new world with the exact same terrain as before on a new version. You do have the db folder though, so it may be possible to recover by downgrading the version, and then escaping the Nether from there. Downgrading is very hard on Bedrock though. (cont.)

Comment: There are many videos that say it's possible, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFoilhy1vm0) one, but the commenters say the MC Launcher program being used to do it can uninstall the game. So be wary if you try that method.